# Paul says in 2 Cor. 5:16 that "even though we once knew Christ by means of the flesh [ kata sarka], we know him thus no longer

Tags: exegesis, 2-corinthians

What was Paul trying to say here? 
"We know him  thus no longer"

Comment: Paul was not a witness of the words of Jesus. Others were. One would hardly expect him to record such quotations.

Comment: Nor was he a witness of the words of the prophet Habakkuk ,yet he recorded such quotations and used them for doctrinal proof text  of Justification by faith.

Comment: Habakkuk's words were already recorded. Paul refers to those records.

Comment: Oh thats right! Still we see that Paul lived also in the era of the closest eyewitnesses to Jesus..which are the apostles.but he still said that he didnt converge with them nor wasnt taught anything from them.

Comment: 'In conference they added nothing to me' Galatians 2:6 only states that the apostles who had precedence had no more to give him. It does not imply 'non-convergence'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to be finding something that simply isn't there.

Consider other translations of this verse, e.g. CSB:

> From now on, then, we do not know anyone from a worldly perspective.
>   Even if we have known Christ from a worldly perspective, yet now we no longer know him in this way.

It's talking about how we should relate to other people, at a spiritual rather than physical level.

There's not the slightest insinuation that any of Jesus's teachings are no longer relevant.

Comment: Even of we have known christ a worldly perspective would mean? And who is the "we"